# Array containing string

Tags: c, arrays, string

Hey I am trying to create an invoice program that is supposed to accept the item name, item price and quantity and store them in a list or array. When I run the program however I get errors. Can someone please help?? I'm noob to c and cannot see how I went wrong, the concept is very simple..

Here is the program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
  {
   char item_name[255];
   float item_price=0;
   float quantity;
   int choice;
   int k;

   for (k=0;choice != 2;k++)
    {
       printf ("Enter item name: ");
       scanf ("%s", item_name[k]);
       printf ("\n");
       printf ("Enter item price: ");
       scanf ("%f", &item_price[k]);
       printf ("\n");
       printf ("Enter item quantity: ");
       scanf ("%f", &quantity[k]);
       printf ("\n\n");
       printf ("Enter another item? Enter '1' for yes and '2' for no: ");
       scanf ("%d", &choice);
    }

  }
```

these are the errors:

sample.c: In function ‘main’:
sample.c:15:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
        scanf ("%s", item_name[k]);
        ^
sample.c:18:32: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
        scanf ("%f", &item_price[k]);
                                ^
sample.c:21:30: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
        scanf ("%f", &quantity[k]);
                              ^
sample.c:25:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
     }
     ^
sample.c:8:10: warning: variable ‘quantity’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    float quantity;
          ^
sample.c:7:10: warning: variable ‘item_price’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    float item_price=0;
          ^

Comment: Please add the complete errors that you get to the question post (not as comments).

Comment: ...well -- it's pretty obvious that we're only allocating space for _one_ item name, price and quantity, then trying to store several of them (in memory that doesn't exist).

Comment: `quantity` and `item_price` aren't arrays so you can't use [] on them.

Comment: ...so, for the OP: Can you control how many items there are? If so, you can allocate arrays large enough for all of them; if not, you'll need to dynamically allocate memory, either by allocating new linked-list entries (which any first-year computer science class in C will show you how to do), or by using `realloc()` or kin to resize an array.

Comment: could you comment the correction of the program above?

Comment: Code should check the return value from `scanf()` calls to insure the field was successfully scanned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char item_name[255];
```

is a single string - not an array of strings.

```
item_name[k]
```

is a char - not a char*

So you need to make item_name a 2D array of strings

```
char item_name[100][255];
```

and then use

```
scanf ("%s", item_name[k]);
```

The next problem is item_price. It also needs to be an array:

```
float item_price[100];
```

And same story with float quantity

```
float quantity[100];
```

And then your are missing a ";" at the end of the last scanf

Finally you need to add

```
if (choice == 2) break;
```

to get out of the loop.

The proposed code allows for 100 items so you should all so add:

```
if (k > 99) break;
```

as the first line in the for-loop